# Preventing extra window split

Tags: vim-windows

`:help` in Vim will do a window split if there is no help window.

If there is a single window, this is fine.

But when there is already a split (vertical or horizontal), I would like to see the help in a new buffer in another window rather that adding yet another split.

How can I get that?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean in another tab? Help does open a new window (sometimes called a split). Try `:tab help`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I do not want to show help in another tab. Basically if there is a single window, it should be split as currently. But if there is another window besides the current, I want help to use it even if it does not show help.

Comment: Ok, sounds like filbranden got it right. I was confused by “But when there is already a split (vertical or horizontal), I would like to see the help in a new buffer in another window rather that adding yet another split.” I think perhaps “would like to see the help in one of the pre-existing windows” is clearer to me.

Comment: You can use `<c-w>T` / `:windcmd T` to move the current window to a new tab. Perhaps you can use `winrn('$')` to get the window count to accomplish your window-to-tab move

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

The Vim help actually includes a recipe to define a new command `:HelpCurwin` to open help in the current window, you can find it under [`:help curwin`](https://vimhelp.org/tips.txt.html#help-curwin).

To define the new command, include this snippet in your vimrc (or a `*.vim` file under directory `~/.vim/plugin` would also work):

```
command -bar -nargs=? -complete=help HelpCurwin execute s:HelpCurwin(<q-args>)
let s:did_open_help = v:false

function s:HelpCurwin(subject) abort
  let mods = 'silent noautocmd keepalt'
  if !s:did_open_help
    execute mods . ' help'
    execute mods . ' helpclose'
    let s:did_open_help = v:true
  endif
  if !getcompletion(a:subject, 'help')->empty()
    execute mods . ' edit ' . &helpfile
  endif
  return 'help ' . a:subject
endfunction
```

After you have that set up, you can open help in the current window with:

```
:HelpCurwin
```

Or, to get help for a particular topic (for example, the `:helpgrep` command):

```
:HelpCurwin :helpgrep
```

Tab completion will work for the command itself (so `:H<Tab>` might complete it if you don't have any other user-commands starting with `H`) and for help topics as well.

Comment: I do not want to open a help on the current window. I want to show it it in another window if it exists. If not, the current window should be split  vertically or horizontally.

Comment: In which of the split? The top, the bottom, left, right?